# How to implement RBF activation function in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, activation-function

I am creating a customized activation function, RBF activation function in particular:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

l2_norm = lambda a,b:  K.sqrt(K.sum(K.pow((a-b),2), axis=0, keepdims=True))

def rbf2(x):
X = #here i need inputs that I receive from previous layer 
Y = # here I need weights that I should apply for this layer
l2 = l2_norm(X,Y)
res = K.exp(-1 * gamma * K.pow(l2,2))
return res
```

The function `rbf2` receives the previous layer as input:

```
#some keras layers
model.add(Dense(84, activation='tanh')) #layer1
model.add(Dense(10, activation = rbf2)) #layer2
```

What should I do to get the inputs from `layer1` and weights from `layer2` to create the customized activation function?

What I am actually trying to do is, implementing the output layer for LeNet5 neural network. The output layer of LeNet-5 is a bit special, instead of computing the dot product of the inputs and the weight vector, each neuron outputs the square of the Euclidean distance between its input vector and its weight vector.

For example, `layer1` has 84 neurons and `layer2` has 10 neurons. In general cases, for calculating output for each of 10 neurons of `layer2`, we do the dot product of 84 neurons of `layer1` and 84 weights in between `layer1` and `layer2`. We then apply `softmax` activation function over it.

But here, instead of doing dot product, each neuron of the `layer2` outputs the square of the Euclidean distance between its input vector and its weight vector (I want to use this as my activation function).

Any help on creating RBF activation function (calculating euclidean distance from inputs the layer receives and weights) and using it in the layer is also helpful.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get **the output** of `layer1` and `layer2` and pass it to your rbf function? If that's the case then are your sure it would work with the current definition of your activation function, since they have different shapes?

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is, implement the output layer for LeNet5 neural network. The output layer of LeNet-5 is a bit special, instead of computing the dot product of the inputs and the weight vector, each neuron outputs the square of the Euclidian distance between its input vector and its weight vector.

Comment: In short, I need the outputs of `layer1` and weights of each neuron of `layer2`. and I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between them.

Comment: Is gamma a single parameter for each neuron or is it a vector? I think it is a single parameter.

Comment: Yes, it is a single parameter. I am using gamma = 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply [define a custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) for this purpose:

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K

class RBFLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, gamma, **kwargs):
        super(RBFLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.gamma = K.cast_to_floatx(gamma)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.mu = self.add_weight(name='mu',
                                  shape=(int(input_shape[1]), self.units),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        super(RBFLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        diff = K.expand_dims(inputs) - self.mu
        l2 = K.sum(K.pow(diff,2), axis=1)
        res = K.exp(-1 * self.gamma * l2)
        return res

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.units)
```

Example usage:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(RBFLayer(10, 0.5))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185572/discussion-on-answer-by-today-how-to-implement-rbf-activation-function-in-keras).

Comment: Can someone explain what gamma,kwargs , self.mu are?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel here. A [custom RBF layer for Keras](https://github.com/PetraVidnerova/rbf_keras) already exists.